# Query Scope to automatically format a time field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm designing a system to track paid leave time for my company and I would like to show the times in standard time to the users. Is there some way to do this with eloquent? So anytime I get a leave request record it automatically formats it to standard time.

I was thinking something like a query scope, but I'm not sure how to do it. I can format the fields manually but would like it done anytime I get a leave record.

Comment: Way too broad a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can achieve this using set and get attributes in the model and formatting the date field with Carbon.

To format the data every time that you are going to save data you can use the attribute setter method

`public function setDateAttribute($value){
   $this->attributes['date'] = Carbon::parse($value)->format(your_required_format);
}`

If you want to format the date you can also create the getter method for that field like this

`public function getDateAttribute(){
  return Carbon::parse( $this->attributes['date'])->format('Your_required_format);
}`

Don't forget to add `use Carbon\Carbon` to import carbon in your model.

Comment: great. i also found more examples here https://scotch.io/tutorials/automatically-format-laravel-database-fields-with-accessors-and-mutators

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.